# Parenting Object Not Working

Tags: armature, bones

I use [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2HCxy4Kh4E)

When I test it like what he did at 7:13, the robot arm is not moving, it only move the Armature

[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Did you select all and then Shift-Click on the armature last to make sure it was hilighted before selecting CTRL-P > Parent with Automatic Weights?

Comment: The file: https://pasteall.org/blend/ddaae180da1c4dee8f7acdb347245d6d

Comment: @JohnEason I Already did that, still the same

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your file apart from the fact that you hadn't done the parenting stage, but even when I did that the objects don't follow the bones despite apparently being parented correctly in the outliner. So I followed the tutorial from scratch with a new project and my arm works fine! I can only suggest that you start again and see if you're successful this time! :^(